# Secure controller access in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my application, I need to secure controller access with Spring Security

In particular, I would like to allow / disallow the access to all controller methods to users based on grants.

Here is an example of Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${path.myapp}" + "/accounts")
public class AccountsController extends AbstractCrudController<AccountsBean, Long> {
...
}
```

In my application, each user has a list of functionalities (defined in a DB table that associates USER->FUNCTIONALITY). User has also a Role, but users with same roles could have the capability to use different functionalities.

When application starts and user do login, I read all functionalities linked to user and I show/hide menu items properly.

Here a bunch of the jsp:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('Anagrafica -> Accounts')" > 
                                <li id="accounts"><a href="${anagraficaPath}/accounts/index.html"><fmt:message key="menu.anagrafica.accounts"/></a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                </sec:authorize>
```

How could I secure this Controller, to deny users that does not have the 'Anagrafica -> Accounts' functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can secure the URI in your security configuration class the one that extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-provide-websecurityconfigureradapter

e.g.

```java
Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("${anagraficaPath}/accounts/*")
            .hasAnyRole("'Anagrafica -> Accounts'");
```

You can then even change your tag to:  
It will then also use the same rule you defined in you config class.

Also if you could enable method level annotations and on the methods in the controller you could use the PreAuthorize e.g.

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Anagrafica -> Accounts')")
public void myControllerMethod() {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to secure a particular controller, you need to use @PreAuthorize annotation just above it, something like one shown below :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('"Anagrafica -> Accounts"')")
public ResponseEntity<T> getAll(){}
```

OR

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('"Anagrafica -> Accounts"')")
public ResponseEntity<T> getAll(){}
```

Note : @PreAuthorize annotation is method level and not class level because PreAuthorize has `@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })` in it.